# Invalidate layout of view controller that’s not visible

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` with a `UICollectionViewController` as the first child view controller, which pushes another view controller onto the stack.

I call `invalidateLatout()` on the collection view layout when the device orientation changes, which resizes the cells. However it doesn’t work when I’ve navigated to the second view controller, presumably because the collection view isn’t visible.

I can see that `invalidateLayout()` is being called, but it doesn’t resize the cells when it’s not visible. Is there any way to force the view to layout in the background? (I’ve tried calling it in `viewWillAppear()` and using `setNeedsLayout()`)

Comment: I believe you wont be able to invalidate layout of collectionView when view is not visible, you can try calling `invalidateLayout` and `reloadData` in `ViewWillAppear` of your `collectionView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working by calling this in `viewWillAppear()`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```